# How to add corrected p-values to a scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, p-value, ggpubr

I am trying to create scatterplots in order to visualize a bunch of correlations I calculated beforehand. I found multiple ways to get correlation coefficients and/or p-values into the plot (e.g. using stat_cor() to add coefficients and p-values to a scatterplot from ggplot2).
Unfortunately I was not able to find a way to insert corrected p-values but only the "raw" p-values. Is there any way (apart from just inserting text by using geom_text()) to directly include these two values (correlation coefficient and corrected p-value) into a scatterplot?

Mainly I tried these three things:

1. Pivoting my data to long format, then creating a graphic which incorporates all 5 scatterplots and then adding coefficients and p-values with stat_cor(). But there seems to be no way to tell stat_cor() to calculate adjusted p-values instead of raw p-values before adding them to the scatterplot

```
adj_apq_scat_gg <- apq_apq156_ctq_metadjagg_fshort_df |>  
    tidyr::pivot_longer(apqg_iv:apqg_cp, names_to = "apq_scales", 
         values_to = "apq_values") |>  
   ggplot(aes(x = resp_percentage, y = apq_values)) +
   geom_point(size=2, color="#808080") +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fullrange=FALSE, level=0.95, 
               color="#4169E1") + 
  facet_wrap(vars(fct_inorder(apq_scales)), ncol = 5) + 
  labs(x = "Response Percentage Adjective Task", y = "APQ Scale Value")  

adj_apq_scat_gg + ggpubr::stat_cor(method = "kendall", 
                         cor.coef.name = "tau")
```

Is there a way to make stat_cor() calculate adjusted p-values? Or maybe a similar function which is able to do this?

2. I used correlation::cor_test() inside the plot() function. But cor_test() only allows the calculation of a correlation between two variables whereas I want to calculate 5 correlations and then adjust the p-values for multiple testing.

```r
adj_apqiv_scat <- plot(correlation::cor_test(apq_apq156_ctq_metadjagg_fshort_df, 
    "resp_percentage", "apqg_iv", method = "kendall", ci = 0.95))
```

This basically gives me what I want but it is not displaying adjusted p-values because I can only feed correlations to the plot() function one by one. Is there any analog function to cor_test(), which is able to calculate more than one correlation and will still display a scatterplot when entered into the plot() function?

3. I used correlation::correlation() to calculate all 5 correlations at once and adjust the p-values all in one step. Unfortunately when entered into the plot() function one is not given scatterplots but rather a really weird looking "star-like" plot. Is there a plotting function which will show scatterplots when an object containing multiple correlations created with correlation::correlation() is entered into it?

```r
adj_apq_kendall_holm_full <- plot(correlation::correlation(data = 
    apq_apq156_ctq_metadjagg_full_df, select = "resp_percentage", 
             select2 = c("apqg_iv", "apqg_pp", "apqg_pm", "apqg_id", 
                         "apqg_cp"), method = "kendall", p_adjust = "holm", 
                         ci = 0.95))
```

All three ways are already pretty close to what I want but they all either can't calculate adjusted p-values or those adjusted p-values cannot be transferred to a scatterplot.
Hope there is a way to solve this.